# Node -WebKit apps on Android or ios platforms

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, node.js, node-webkit

Can I develop apps for android or ios platforms using node-webkit?
if no is there any possibility exist in future to develop apps for android or ios platforms using node-webkit?

Note: I have googled about this and got to know that we can't develop app using node-webkit  for android or ios platforms right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; only Linux, Mac OS X and Windows are supported by node-webkit.

Comment: Its really too bad. I would love to see this also but I think that the limitation is that Chromium would need to be ported to the other platforms. I am quite sure that Apple would never allow this to work properly for control reasons and Android also would prefer that it just use the native Android web engines rather than allowing a broad tool like Chromium bypass all the hooks in Android.

Comment: I have spent some times on this as well. From what I could read you can install node on your device. You have to install a terminal and then install npm and node so I guess it could be possible now but not very user frendly or at least nothing native. This should really be looked in to. It would make an accessible mutli platform tool based on javascript.